# How to reclassify images in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am attempting to reclassify continuous data to categorical data using Matlab.  The following script takes a 4-band (Red, Green, Blue, nIR) aerial image and calculates the normalized difference vegetation index (i.e. a vegetation index showing healthy green vegetation).  The script then rescales the values from (-1 to 1) to (0 - 255).  This is the matrix I am trying to reclassify in the third section of the script `%% Reclassify Imag1 matrix`.  I am attempting to use conditional statements to perform the reclassification, although this may be the wrong approach.  The reclassification step in the script does not have any apparent effect.

*How can I reclassify continuous values (0 - 255) to categorical values (1, 2, 3, 4) on a cell by cell basis?*

---

```
file = 'F:\path\to\naip\image\4112107_ne.tif';
[Z R] = geotiffread(file);
outputdir = 'F:\temp\';

%% Make NDVI calculations
NIR = im2single(Z(:,:,4));
red = im2single(Z(:,:,3));
ndvi = (NIR - red) ./ (NIR + red);
ndvi = double(ndvi);

%% Stretch NDVI to 0-255 and convert to 8-bit unsigned integer
ndvi = floor((ndvi + 1) * 128); % [-1 1] -> [0 256]
ndvi(ndvi < 0) = 0;             % not really necessary, just in case & for symmetry
ndvi(ndvi > 255) = 255;         % in case the original value was exactly 1
Imag1 = uint8(ndvi);

%% Reclassify Imag1 matrix
if (150 <= Imag1)
    Imag1 = 1;
elseif (150 > Imag1) & (140 < Imag1)
    Imag1 = 2;
elseif (140 > Imag1) & (130 < Imag1)
    Imag1 = 3;
elseif (130 >= Imag1)
    Imag1 = 4;

end

%% Write the results to disk
tiffdata = geotiffinfo(file);
outfilename = [outputdir 'reclass_ndvi' '.tif'];  
geotiffwrite(outfilename, Imag1, R, 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag', tiffdata.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag) 

disp('Processing complete')
```

Comment: To deal with the error you posted do `&` instead of `&&`. Same with `|`

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri, I have fixed the script (and cleared the error message) based on your comments.  Now I have to deal with the main question, as the script does not produce the reclassified results I am after.

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to see if the conditional statement gets entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Imag1 = [ 62  41 169 118 210;
         133 158  96 149 110;
         211 200  84 194  29;
         209  16  15 146  28;
          95 144  13 249 170];

Imag1(find(Imag1 <= 130)) = 4;
Imag1(find(Imag1 >= 150)) = 1;
Imag1(find(Imag1 >  140)) = 2;
Imag1(find(Imag1 >  130)) = 3;
```

Result:

```
Imag1 =

    62    41   169   118   210
   133   158    96   149   110
   211   200    84   194    29
   209    16    15   146    28
    95   144    13   249   170

Imag1 =

   4   4   1   4   1
   3   1   4   2   4
   1   1   4   1   4
   1   4   4   2   4
   4   2   4   1   1
```

I can go into the logic in detail if you like, but I wanted to confirm that this gives your expected results first.

---

Some updates based on comments on the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953250/how-to-classify-a-matrix-within-a-matlab-parfor-loop) to eliminate the unnecessary `find` and make the code more robust and independent of execution order.

```
Imag2 = zeros(size(Imag1));
Imag2(Imag1 >= 150) = 1;
Imag2((Imag1 >  140) & (Imag1 < 150)) = 2;
Imag2((Imag1 >  130) & (Imag1 < 141)) = 3;
Imag2(Imag1 <= 130) = 4;
```

Note that the results are now in `Imag2` instead of overwriting `Imag1`.